# How to write JSON code from PHP in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, variables

This is my `employeeshift.js` code and I can't figure out how to do a PHP code in a JavaScript file

This is my code inside the `employeeshift.js` but my `var inorno` is null

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var inorno= "<?php echo json_encode($inOrOut ); ?>";

if(inorno=="0"){

 $('.Sales1').hide();
 }else{
$('.Sales1').show();
} 

});
```

Comment: but then i will have to write <script></script> ?

Comment: I moved my comment to answer, no you just include it normally as Javascript file `<script type="text/javascript" src="...">`

Answer (score 0):

You can't (and probably shouldn't, even if you could) write PHP into a JavaScript file. PHP on your server doesn't "know" that it should execute any PHP code you've placed there. An alternative would be to put the JavaScript, surrounded by `<script></script>` tags, in a PHP file, and then your could should work.

Comment: If however you really need the file to be a JavaScript file, your best bet would be to write a small PHP script that simply returns the variable as a JSON string, use AJAX to request it, and then use it in your JS file after the callback. That, however, is a bit more complex.

Comment: yea cause i was just wanted to put my js code in a js file the only problem is the php code

Comment: Then I'd read up on jQuery's .ajax function and how you can use that to get the variable from a separate PHP script. It's not too complex. W3C Schools has a nice introduction to it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Rename your js file to php ....or past js code to php file then do like below

```
        <?php 
        //some of your main php file code ..........
?>
<script type="text//javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

    var inorno= "<?php echo json_encode($inOrOut ); ?>";

    if(inorno=="0"){

     $('.Sales1').hide();
     }else{
    $('.Sales1').show();
    } 

        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file is probably NOT parsed as PHP script, unless you changed some server config. One way would be to rename it to `employeeshift.js.php`

Answer (score 0):

if this is your JS file than var value will always be null, you can assign value to a var only when the file is php and you are adding this in script tag